# euclid's extended algorithm C ++

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm having an issue with Euclid's Extended Algorithm. (ax+by=gcd(a,b)) I'm trying to determine both the GCD and x and y. The GCD isn't a problem but using the loop method something is going wrong with x and y. Normally one number comes up as 0 and the other is an abnormally large negative number. Code follows:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

main ()
{
    int a,b,q,x,lastx,y,lasty,temp,temp1,temp2,temp3;
    cout << "Please input a" << endl;
    cin >> a; 
    cout << "Please input b" << endl;
    cin >> b;
    if (b>a) {//we switch them
        temp=a; a=b; b=temp;
    }
    //begin function
    x=0;
    y=1;
    lastx=1;
    lasty=0;
    while (b!=0) {
        q= a/b;
        temp1= a%b;
        a=b;
        b=temp1;

        temp2=x-q*x;
        x=lastx-q*x;
        lastx=temp2;

        temp3=y-q*y;
        y=lasty-q*y;
        lasty=temp3;
    }

    cout << "gcd" << a << endl;
    cout << "x=" << lastx << endl;
    cout << "y=" << lasty << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two of your assignments are wrong they should be:

```
    temp2 = x;
    x=lastx-q*x;
    lastx = temp2;

    temp3 = y;
    y = lasty-q*y;
    lasty=temp3;
```

Example output with the above fixes:

```
Please input a
54
Please input b
24
gcd6
x=1
y=-2
```

Answer (score 15):

Although the question has been asked a long time ago, but the answer will help someone who were finding C++ implementation of extended euclidean algorithm.

**Here is a recursive C++ implementation:**

```
int xGCD(int a, int b, int &x, int &y) {
    if(b == 0) {
       x = 1;
       y = 0;
       return a;
    }

    int x1, y1, gcd = xGCD(b, a % b, x1, y1);
    x = y1;
    y = x1 - (a / b) * y1;
    return gcd;
}
```

**Example with code:**

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   int a = 99, b = 78, x, y, gcd;

   if(a < b) std::swap(a, b);

   gcd = xGCD(a, b, x, y);
   std::cout << "GCD: " << gcd << ", x = " << x << ", y = " << y << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

**Input:**

a = 99, b =78

**Output:**

GCD: 3, x = -11, y = 14

Comment: You forgot to include the std::swap!! use <utility> for c++11 or greather or <algorithm> for lower versions